# How to unset csrf in modelviewset of django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-1.6

How to unset csrf in modelviewset of django-rest-framework?

I'll use viewsets.ModelViewSet(http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets.html#modelviewset) of django-rest-framework.

And my app is api server. So I don't need to use csrf.

But I don't know how to unset csrf.

Please give me a example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSRF is only enforced if you're using SessionAuthentication.
If you're using one of the other form of authentication (eg TokenAuthentication) then it won't be required.

Comment: I'm using this in my viewset: 'authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)' but i'm still getting csrf error when using the Token header

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap dispatch method of ModelViewSet with [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt):

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyModelViewSet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

or you can achieve the same effect by wrapping the view in **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^snippets/$', csrf_exempt(snippet_list), name='snippet-list'),
url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', csrf_exempt(snippet_detail), name='snippet-detail'),
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this in conjunction with SessionAuthentication? I have, and I'm almost certain the DRF authentication middleware entirely ignores any such decorator.

Comment: So anyway to do that? This answer really cannot work. I have serval viewset need to be protected by csrf, while only one should not be protected by csrf.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure no api-auth is included in your urlpatterns.